# Created a new field in Drupal, trying to assign it to multiple content types

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've created a field called "field_vote" in Drupal, and it was automatically assigned where I created it, to a content type called toolkits.

I also want to assign it to resources, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/[YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE]/fields`

2 Under `Add existing field`, choose the existing field you wanna add. (`field_vote` in your case)

3 Hit `Save` to customize your field settings, and you're done.

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your "resources" content type and click to "manage fields". You can then add an existing field to that content type. I'm assuming this is Drupal 7 since you didn't specify.